# Unresolved external symbol _main error when building

Tags: c++, header, header-files

I trying to learn C++ and just keep getting error after error... Its not even anything I am doing but rather visual studios doing... and I think my text book.
I am trying to learn by example form my text books source files and I just want this program to run. I included the raw .cpp and .h files in a folder called new folder. I really just do not understand why I can't get it to run. I got to to compile once and it  cmd just said "not readable batch file". 
What am I doing wrong and any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
'Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   C:\Users\tsquare\Desktop\Class Clock (book)\Class Clock (book)\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)  Class Clock (book)

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\tsquare\Desktop\Class Clock (book)\Debug\Class Clock (book).exe    1   1   Class Clock (book)'
```

This .zip as the full project and like I said it is just example from my text book. I can follow the logic of what is going on but I can't understand why it won't run.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/6mj4svt1669wg6g/Class+Clock+%28book%29.zip

Please let me know what you think I can do to get it to work.
PS 
I plan on emailing my Prof. with this question though it take long to reply because he as a lot of students.
Thanks

Comment: Without downloading the zip file, you haven't a main() function

Comment: Where are the source files in the zip? I can't seem to find them...
Or maybe that's the problem as @MarcoA. said. You have to have a main function in a cpp source file which I think you're missing. Every C/C++ program has to have a `main()` function which is the entry point for your program. In there, you can create an object from your class and use it. You can't just compile and run a class on it's own without any other source files in your project.

Comment: @ Marco A
OMG I guess I am dumb... you are right there is not a main... I added them to my project and ran and was like wtf... Yes you are right thanks for pointing out the obvious to me. :/ 
Also @ adman10693 this is files form my text book in .zip
http://www.mediafire.com/download/6mj4svt1669wg6g/Class+Clock+%28book%29.zip

Sorry for wasting your time.